# Elasticsearch Cross Cluster Search behind nginx proxy

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, logging, elasticsearch-5

I want to setup sort of aggregation for multiple Elasticsearch clusters based on Cross Cluster Search feature.
I have the following layout:

[image: layout]

As seed for Cross Cluster Search I am using the only available via network cluster address.
After querying I am getting error:

```
[elasticsearch][172.16.10.100:9300] connect_timeout[30s]
```

I can't change `publish_host` for nodes, because that address used inside the cluster for node communication.

Is there any option to force Cross Cluster Search to use only provided address?
Or any other way to setup kinda proxy for user to be able to search/visualize in kibana data from multiple isolated elasticsearch clusters?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @AnyMoose No. I think it is about proper configuration or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the only solution is to upgrade to Elasticsearch 7, which provides the `cluster.remote.${cluster_alias}.proxy` option where you can specify the incoming IP address for the cross cluster search.